# How to get access token and use it

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, ngrok

I am working on creating bot for Microsoft teams in C#. I have a sample code ([basic echo bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)) that works fine in emulator. I created an app in teams app studio and entered my API end points in Bot section. I download the package and upload it as custom package in teams.

Now, when I add this app and try communicate with Bot, I get unauthorize error in API (using ngrok). I guess what’s going on here is that I don’t have the access token i.e. when someone install it, teams should give you access token, right?

What I don’t know is how teams will give me the access token and where in the process that access token will be used?

So basically, when someone clicks on “Add” button in teams app store, how the access token are passed.

**@update**

Note:-I have done the app registration as well.

So i did bot channel registration in Azure and added my ngrok end points. I copied the "MicrosoftAppId" and "MicrosoftAppPassword" in appsettings file. It is working fine in emulator as well as "test on web chat" in Azure bot management portal. I also connected it to Teams channel from portal itself. when i navigate to teams from the channel link, my bot is working as expected.
[image]

After that i opened app studio and entered all the details. In Bot section, i selected existing bot id and entered my MicrosoftAppId from azure and it worked.

what I still don't understand is, when someone install the app, teams should be sending some information to my end point, right?

Comment: for testing purpose, i created a Azure bot as well that works fine but i don't know how  to get access token and use it to communicate in Teams

Comment: Have you set correctly the ClientId/ClientSecret?

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos that is my question. where to add the clientid/client secret and how we get that?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i downloaded the sample code from https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot

Comment: I might have mistaken this from the time I played with bot framework on v3. The docs contain many changes. You should try following the deploy to azure guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: You have to add your clientId and secreot on `appsettings.json` file on your bot project.

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos I already did these steps. It's working fine in Azure test bot. I am trying to find out how to get access token from Teams when someone install it.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth then you should look at this sample about the authentication with MS Teams

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i am new to this. So, how you get the clientid in the first place. When someone install the app, teams must be sending these information. so my question is how to get that token

Comment: @DeveshTiwari You will need to add the client id and client secret in the applications config page. The client id is the id of the Bot you get while you create a Bot from App Studio. The client secret is the password of the Bot you created.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I updated my question with more details

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos updated question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to your code it is hard/impossible to determine the cause of your issue.

I suggest instead you take a fresh start by using one of the Teams bot examples that are shared :

- [57.teams-conversation-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot)

if you do require authentication in your bot:

- [Authentication flow for bots - Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication)
- 46.teams-auth
- 52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config

pleanty other teams examples as well in that repo:

- 50.teams-messaging-extensions-search
- 51.teams-messaging-extensions-action
- 53.teams-messaging-extensions-action-preview
- 54.teams-task-module
- 55.teams-link-unfurling
- 56.teams-file-upload
- 57.teams-conversation-bot
- 58.teams-start-new-thread-in-channel